# vuejs catch error and display error message based on field that has error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to display error messages

this works:

```
.catch(error => {
  swal(error.response.data.errors.username[0], "Error", "error");
});
```

this one doesn't display second error message even if it has error

```
.catch(error => {
    if (error.response.data.errors.username[0]) {
      swal(error.response.data.errors.username[0], "Error", "error");
    } else if (error.response.data.errors.confirmpassword[0]) {
      swal(error.response.data.errors.confirmpassword[0], "Error", "error");
    }
 });
```

Comment: I think is because you are using `else if`, because of that, if the username field has an error the second `if` is skipped

Comment: Even if the username field has no error the error for Confirm Password is not getting displayed

Comment: ok, but if the username field has no error, the username array doesn't exist, can you share the response from  the server ?

Comment: Ok I got it. I have to test only error.response.data.errors.username and not the error.response.data.errors.username[0]. Thanks for your input man! Appreciate it.